# dotnetcore http thread async await conundrum

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core

in a dotnet core http application we have a call that performs work, makes several http calls out to backing services, and returns. It was all async await. which meant that the call was waiting for the backing services to perform their work before returning the call to the client. this was causing the call to timeout.

the solution that was presented was to remove the async await all the way down as low as we could then essentially just wrap the http calls (still async task methods) in pragma tags that suppress the warning/compiler error.

This makes me nervous because you don't guarantee that the final (or any) of http requests are made before the calling thread returns and the async machines associated with that thread are cleaned up.

Am I missing something? is this one of those weird but usable situations? or would it be more appropriate to spin off threads to handle those http calls?

Comment: If you don't want to wait for a task, don't await the task. It's that simple. No need to remove all the async and await keywords.

Comment: Are you awaiting after each call? If so you might be able to use Task.WaitAll(tasks); that way all calls are processing at the same time and you might not timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about [fire-and-forget](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html), and you're right to be worried. There are several problems with fire-and-forget. This is because "forget" means "forget", and it's *almost always* the wrong decision to have your application just forget about something.

If there's an exception calling one of those inner HTTP requests, that exception will be ignored, unless you have special logic handling that situation. And remember, there's no outer request anymore, so returning an error isn't possible (there's nowhere for it to return to). So you have the possibility of silently-swallowed errors. This should make you nervous.

Also, you have the problem of not informing ASP.NET that you have ongoing background work. By returning early, you're telling ASP.NET to send the response and that everything is fine, even though in reality, the work isn't done and you have no idea when it will be done or even whether it will succeed. The point here is that nothing upstream of your code (including ASP.NET, IIS/Kestrel, proxies, load balancers) has any idea that your code is still working - after all, your code did just tell all those things that it's *done* handling that request. Will ASP.NET respond to a shutdown request? Sure! Can IIS do its periodic app pool recycle? Sure! Can your proxy take that node out of rotation when doing a rolling upgrade? Sure! Will your load balancer send it more work since it's not doing anything? Sure! As far as any of those systems know, your app isn't actually handling that request, and that can cause problems, like your "fire and forget" work suddenly disappearing - again, with no exceptions or logs or anything. This should make you nervous.

I'd say the best approach is to fix downstream calls, if possible. Also look into asynchronous concurrency, e.g., starting several calls and then `await Task.WhenAll`. If these approaches aren't sufficient, then I'd recommend a proper distributed architecture: have the API write to a persistent queue, and have the background work done by a separate application that processes that queue.